# Redirection, proxies and RewriteEngine

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My website (`www.example.com`) has this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/sub/(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

The folder structure is similar to this one:

```
/ root
| .htaccess
| index.php
| / sub
| | more.html
| | cats.jpeg
| | / folder
| | | index.php
```

What the `.htaccess` file should do is:

- Serve `/sub/cats.jpeg` when opening `sub.example.com/cats.jpeg` (but don't redirect, serve as proxy)
- Redirect (301) any access to open `/sub/*` to `sub.example.com/*`

Now this works mostly, but it fails sometimes:

- `sub.example.com/folder` goes to `sub.example.com/sub/folder/`
- `sub.example.com/folder/` works as expected

Why? Could you guys help me? Provide a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm this is little bit tricky problem. I had to recreate this directory structure to investigate what is going on.

This is actually due to `mod_dir` playing spoilsport. `mod_dir` detects if a Request URI is a directory and adds a trailing slash if your URI has a missing one.

You are requesting `/folder` without a trailing slash. Your rewrite rule rewrited it to `/sub/folder` and `mod_dir` does a `301` redirect to `/sub/folder/`. Obviously when you request `sub.example.com/folder/` then `mod_dir` won't do anything since it already has a trailing slash in rewritten URI `sub.example.com/sub/folder/`

To fix this issue have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sub(/.*)?$ http://sub.example.com$1 [NE,NC,L,R=302]

# adds a trailing slash if rewritten URI is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^((?!sub/).*)$ /sub/$1/ [L,NC]

# just rewrite to /sub/<uri>    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^((?!sub/).*)$ /sub/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly `sub.example.com/folder` still leads to `sub.example.com/sub/folder/`.

Comment: That is only on your browser with old cache. Test that in a new browser.

Comment: Yup, forgot to clear cache, thank you for your help. Also, one last thing, any requests to `sub.example.com/sub/folder/` still get an answer, any way to stop that?